# Trouble using FRED API in Python -- cannot load module

Tags: python, import, module, installation, economics

I am trying to use this API for the Federal Reserve Economic Data (FRED):
https://github.com/zachwill/fred

I installed the three modules that the documentation said are required.  I get this error:

```
import fred

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import fred
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\fred\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Dummy file to make this a package.
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\fred\fred.py", line 21, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name xml2dict
```

I then installed xml2dict and installed fred again.  When I now do import xml2dict first and then import fred, I get the exact same error.

I had a hard time learning to install modules in Python but thought I finally had it figured out.  I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong here though and could use some help.  Thanks!

For Zach: This is the problem I'm currently having:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    fred.series('GNPCA')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\fred\api.py", line 90, in series
    return Fred().series(path, **kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\fred\core.py", line 100, in series
    return self.get('series', path, **kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\fred\core.py", line 36, in get
    request = requests.get(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\requests-0.13.2-py2.6.egg\requests\api.py", line 54, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\requests-0.13.2-py2.6.egg\requests\safe_mode.py", line 37,     in wrapped
    return function(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\requests-0.13.2-py2.6.egg\requests\api.py", line 42, in     request
return s.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\requests-0.13.2-py2.6.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 230, in request
    r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\requests-0.13.2-py2.6.egg\requests\models.py", line 601, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.stlouisfed.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with     url: /fred/series?series_id=GNPCA&api_key=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the developer of the `fred` package. This is completely my fault — I had the `setup.py` file incorrectly configured, and I just pushed an update that should take care of this issue. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks!  Just installed it successfully.  It looks like a very nice tool.

Comment: I am still having trouble with this.  I tried following your example under usage.  I did import fred and then fred.key('my key from FRED').  When I then tried doing fred.series('GNPCA'), I got an error ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.stlouisfed.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /fred/series?series_id=GNPCA&api_key=[deleted my key].  Is that example command working on your end?

Answer (score 3):

**Tips on Installing modules in general:**

What's generally easiest is to use `pip` or `easy_install` (or a binary installer if available) - that way all you need to do is `easy_install fred` and everything will automatically be downloaded that's required (as long as it's been configured properly).

Check out setuptools at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and install that for your appropriate OS version. You will then get a command called `easy_install` which will be installed in a certain location depending on your OS/setup (the docs do mention where though).
[You can also `easy_install pip` as `pip` is effectively `easy_install`'s successor]

Then hopefully, all you need to do is `easy_install fred` (which will automatically find at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fred), and it will download the latest version and all dependencies for you. Fire up your interpreter and `import fred` should "just work".

Comment: Thanks.  I just did exactly what you suggested.  I reinstalled fred using easy_install and the install was successful.  Unfortunately I got the exact same error message.

Comment: @DavidM I'll give it a go here in a mo', see if I can't get more info. from it

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.  At the very least it was worth figuring out how to use easy_install, but it would be nice to get the API for this valuable data source working too.

Comment: @DavidM well... it looks like fred has some weird absolute imports, and xml2dict isn't configured as a module to install correctly - so between them... ugh - it might be worth contacting the author of FRED and pointing them to this thread. However, depending what you want to do with FRED stuff, it looks like a fairly simple use of `lxml` / `json` / `requests` (sorry I don't have enough time to dig further)